# How to specify pytorch as a package requirement on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch, setup.py, pypi

I have a python package which depends on pytorch and which I’d like windows users to be able to install via pip (the specific package is: https://github.com/mindsdb/lightwood, but I don’t think this is very relevant to my question).

What are the best practices for going about this ?

Are there some project I could use as examples ?

It seems like the pypi hosted version of torch & torchvision aren’t windows compatible and the “getting started” section suggests installing from the custom pytorch repository, but beyond that I’m not sure what the ideal solution would be to incorporate this as part of a setup script.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the best practices for going about this ?

If your project depends on other projects that are not distributed through *PyPI* then you have to inform the users of your project one way or another. I recommend the following combination:

- clearly specify (in your project's documentation pages, or in the project's *long description*, or in the *README*, or anything like this) which dependencies are not available through PyPI (and possibly the reason why, with the appropriate links) as well as the possible locations to get them from;
- to facilitate the user experience, publish alongside your project a pre-prepared [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file with the appropriate `--find-links` options.

The reason why (or main reason, there are others), is that anyone using *pip* assumes that (by default) everything will be downloaded from *PyPI* and nowhere else. In other words anyone using *pip* puts some trust into *pypi.org* as a source for Python project distributions. If *pip* were suddenly to download artifacts from other sources, it would breach this trust. It should be the user's decision to download from other sources.

So you could provide in your project's documentation an example of `requirements.txt` file like the following:

```
# ...
torch===1.4.0  --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torchvision===0.5.0  --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
# ...
```

---

**Update**

The best solution would be to help the maintainers of the projects in question to publish *Windows* *wheels* on *PyPI* directly:

- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24310
- https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1774
- https://pypi.org/help/#file-size-limit

Comment: I mean, that's essentially what I plan on doing right now (or rather, I have a custom install script that downloads those separately), I just wonder if there's a better solution than "not doing what I want to do" :p

Comment: There are many other alternatives, but most likely they would all require much more work and would breach out of the best practices. The `requirements.txt` solution is easy, flexible, well known, follows best practices and supported by pip and many other tools. It is how pytorch is distributed after all, and it works for them. Alternatives... Build the wheels (or download them) and publish them yourself on PyPI under a different name. _Vendor_ the dependencies. Distribute your project on _conda_ (maybe, I don't know). Use alternative distribution methods (think _zipapp_, _pex_, _shiv_, etc.).

Comment: @George Does that answer your question? Any further clarification needed?

Comment: It doesn't, since building the wheels and publishing them myself is not easy at all, as it would require dozens of supported configurations to all be covered in the build process and building pytorch is non-trivial. Not to mention, the issue that's stopping pytroch on windows from working via pypi is one I'd most likely encounter myself when doing this, I am with an extremely high certainty worst than the pytroch developer and doing this job, and since they failed I can assume I also will.

Comment: This is, for example, a better "solution" to this problem, aka one that doesn't require hundreds of hours of work and a separate deployment infrastructure nor does it require giving up: https://github.com/mindsdb/lightwood/blob/master/setup.py#L40 | But I don't think it's ideal, so I'm hoping to find some better answers

Comment: What about all the other suggestions? Recreating the wheels from scratch is obviously the most work-intensive, and the less likely to succeed, no doubt about that. What about using _conda_? And most importantly I am still not sure what are the arguments against properly documenting where to find the dependencies (`--find-links` and `requirements.txt`). Once again, that is how _pytorch_ itself is distributed, as it is the right thing to do (since for whatever reason it's not on PyPI), it is definitely the best practice you asked for in your question.

Comment: That code seems an incredibly bad idea. Forcing the installation like that is very much against bad practices. But... if it is what you want to do, there are better ways to do it (less likely to fail), you could open a new question and ask for suggestions on how to improve this.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what this question is asking, suggestions on how to make pypi install those dependencies :p And yes, it's bad practice, that's why I don't want to post it as an answer here and close the question just yet.

Comment: Maybe ask the _pytorch_ maintainers what happened with this intention: "_we might push windows binaries to PyPI from 1.4 onwards_"? https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24310 -- I mean I still don't see any reason why it's not on PyPI to begin with. I doubt size really is an issue. I believe the _PyPI_ maintainers are open to push these limits on a case by case basis if needed: https://pypi.org/help/#file-size-limit and https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/86

Comment: @George As to calling `pip` from `setup.py`, [read this first](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program): 1. Most likely this calls _pip_ while _pip_ is already running, which might lead to undefined behavior. 2. This code runs only when installing from source (_sdist_), not from wheels, and since pip builds wheels and caches them locally for following installations, _pytorch_ will not be installed. 3. The best way of calling _pip_ is `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'my_package'])`, anything else is likely to give undefined results.

Comment: should this be an issue if I only distribute my packages as sdist ?. As for 1, true, but I'm afraid I find it's too hard to users (especially less technical one on windows) to complete separate steps of installing pytroch, so I'd rather take UB on some machines than have the package no work (It seems to behave fine on most). As for 3, true, I should probably change to subprocess.

Comment: **1.** If people can use your library, they can install _pytorch_, and it's not even your responsibility. **2.** I believe it could be a problem, since (as far as I know) when installing from a _sdist_, _pip_ tries to build a _wheel_ first then caches it on the local file system and then does the actual installation from this _wheel_. For the following installations, _pip_ directly uses the cached _wheel_ and thus skips `setup.py` entirely (no _pytorch_!). Try it. **3.** The important bit is `[sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', ...]`, to make absolutely sure the current Python interpreter is used.