# Issue with certain installs for extended package specification for requirements.txt when `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

In my requirements.txt file, I have this

`torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

However, when I try to do

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

I get this

```
Invalid requirement: 'torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 92, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1617, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1607, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3376, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1383, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3164, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 17), (line:1, col:18)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\santosh\documents\github\zakta\zaktaenv2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'torchvis'"
```

So I think it has something to do with the extended pip command, so I think I need to format it differently in my requirements.txt file somehow, maybe with quotes, $, or {}.

Comment: requirements.txt is not command line of pip, separate two packages into two lines.

Comment: You have a full `pip` command in your file. That does not belong there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858804/11138259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**
As @georgexsh and @Klaus D. commented, `requirements.txt` is not command line of pip, so you need to get rid of those command and have two packages in separate lines.

Here is the link to the documentation on [requirements file format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format).

You can simply have these two line in your `requirements.txt` file:

```
torch==1.4.0
torchvision==0.5.0
```

then run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I am wondering about '-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html'. Does it go with the first line, second, both?